# Issue with motor (discord.py)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm currently using **motor** (async wrapper for **pymongo**) in my discord bot and I get this error

```
py
Ignoring exception in on_message
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 361, in _run_event
      await coro(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/workspace/cogs/helpful.py", line 177, in message_increment
      data = await self.message_database.find_one({"_id": message.author.id})
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='discord.py: on_message' coro=<Client._run_event() running at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py:361>> got Future <Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/futures.py:384]> attached to a different loop
```

Does anyone know why gets raised?

Line 177:

```py
 @commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
    async def message_increment(self, message: discord.Message):
 
        if message.author.bot:
            return
 
        data = await self.message_database.find_one({"_id": message.author.id})
 
        if data is None:
            await self.message_database.insert_one(
                {"_id": message.author.id, "messages": 1, "name": str(message.author)}
            )
 
        if data is not None:
            await self.message_database.update_one(
                {"_id": message.author.id}, {"$inc": {"messages": 1}}
            )
            await self.message_database.update_one(
                {"_id": message.author.id}, {"$set": {"name": str(message.author)}}
            )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack sifte! Could you provide a code snippet of your `on_message`, more specifically the surrounding code of line 177 (derived from your error)? This will help us on stack to help you solve your problem faster. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @Bagle. Heres the code: https://pastebin.com/AZCq13r0

Comment: Hey sifte, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include the code as a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) (sometimes links die)

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've figured out how to solve my error. All I needed to do was move my `AsyncIOMotorClient` instance to somewhere where my bot loop exists. Thanks everyone that tried to help me!